# Jenkins & GitLab & Docker integration fails

Tags: docker, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

## Jenkins

In Jenkins I decided to use the remote docker feature.
So I installed `docker.io` on the linux server and use this pipeline.

```
node {
    stage('Example') {
        docker.withServer('tcp://docker.example.org:2375') {
            docker.image('stefanscherer/node-windows:10').inside {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails with a error message about the volume configuration.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'stefanscherer/node-windows:10'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Docker Test:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Docker Test:rw,z'.
See 'docker run --help'.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:133)
```

Maybe the problem is that I try to combine a linux Jenkins with a docker Windows?
But I read for this is the `experimental` option which should allow using Linux containers.

## GitLab

GitLab-Runner installed via this guide. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html
Then I connected it and selected `docker` as executor.

When I remove the `hosts` from `daemon.json` I get this error message.

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: client version 1.18 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version (executor_docker.go:1161:0s)
```

How to get a version which supports the newer API?
I read an article that GitLab is waiting for LTS EOL (End-of-Life). I think for CentOS or something else.

When I have the `hosts` set up in `daemon.json` I get this error message.

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.18/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. (executor_docker.go:1161:0s)
```

Thats because the runner can't find Docker because Docker is only listening on the TCP port.
I tried adding `//./pipe/docker_engine` to the `hosts` of `daemon.json` but it didn't work. The docker service is crashing immediately.

## Docker

**Windows Server 2016**

`daemon.json`

```
{
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"],
    "experimental": true
}
```

## Goal

My goal is to build my jobs from (linux) Jenkins and (linux) GitLab on the (windows) Docker.

## Problem

**Jenkins** is not working in general because of some settings maybe or because it tries to mount windows paths?

**GitLab** is expecting an old API which the docker doesn't offer.

Comment: Is there a reason to use Windows for the docker installlation? I configured everything with Linux (Ubuntu) and it worked like a charm. In any case you can also include the VM as a jenkins slave node. Right now you are executing the pipeline in the master into a remote docker server.

Comment: It seems to me that jenkins is failing because it is trying to mount Windows paths (even it should work) but the runners issue is still pending for Windows. Check this https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2176. So I would go for a Linux installlation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Goal**

You are in the right track, distribute your CI pipeline allows easy scalation and containers are the ideal solution for this.

### **Jenkins**

In the [Docker Pipeline Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-a-remote-docker-server) it is explained:

> For inside() to work, the Docker server and the Jenkins agent must use
>   the same filesystem, so that the workspace can be mounted.

So give a try with other command (for instance withRun) and see, in any case, I miss some credentials here. You can also configure a new Jenkins node for Docker and there you can specify the path where the jobs are executed.

### **GitLab**

The GitLab runner issue on Windows is planned to be included in 11.8 release (Feb 2019) as it is described [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3488).

### **Conclusion**

I would go for a Linux installlation if you cannot wait until the new GitLab release and I would add a new Jenkins node for the docker configuration as it is described [here](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/).

Comment: Yes okay you're right. I must go this direction. But yes I can wait for 11.8 to be released. So then this problem is solved :-) Thanks.